# Ember.js and PHP API

Tags: php, json, rest, ember.js, http-method

I am currently having an issue learning the basics of Ember and how it communicates with a backend service.

Here is what I'm doing in `router.js`:

```
Rugby.RugbyRosterRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        model: function(){

            return [{

                    firstname:$.getJSON("/RugbyAPI")
                    // $.getJSON("/RugbyAPI") returns "John"

                }];

            //return this.store.find('roster');
        },

        renderTemplate: function(controller) {
            this.render('rugby/roster', {controller: controller});
            // tried this as well
            //this.render('rugby/roster', controller);

        }
    });
```

But this is whats rendered.... `[object Object]`

I guess my question is how would I deal with this 'object'. I have been stuck for the past day but now luck...

EDIT:

I run this command in the web browser console...

```
$.getJSON("/RugbyAPI", function(data) { console.log(data) });
```

This is the result:

```
-> Object {readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
-> John
```

My guess is that I have to parse to the key that I need to display... But I can't seem to parse to it.... `['responseJSON']`, `['firstname']`, etc., nothings working...

Answer (score 1):

```
{controller: controller}
```

Is an object.

Try:

```
this.render('rugby/roster', controller);
```

or:

```
this.render('rugby/roster', controller.propertyName);
```

Comment: if `controller.propertyName` is still giving `[object Object]` then try `console.log(controller.propertyName)` and see what you got in it

Comment: but console.log(controller) gives me an object